# virtualbox: new host key combination not saved after change

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want to change my host key combination in the Virtualbox that is currently  <kbd>alt gr</kbd>. To do so, I go to:

```
file -> preferences -> Input -> Virtual Machine
```

, then clicking on the field beside `Host Key Combination`, by typing my new host key (e.g. <kbd>right ctrl</kbd>) and then `OK`.

However, if I switch on my virtual systems or if I come back to

```
file -> preferences -> Input -> Virtual Machine
```

I can see that my changes are not saved.

Any idea what can be the reason?

**My system:**

virtualbox-4.3_4.3.10-93012~Ubuntu~raring_amd64.deb ***with extension pack***

host: Ubuntu 13.10

guest: windows XP & windows 7 professional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem (OS X, VirtualBox 4.3.10).  You can see the current host key code with

```
VBoxManage getextradata global GUI/Input/HostKeyCombination
```

Set it with

```
VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/Input/HostKeyCombination xx
```

where "xx" is the new code.  I changed the value from 55 to 54 to switch from left to right command key (Apple keyboard) - you might need different values.

Comment: OK it works fine, thanks! The real trick was to find the good value though. In my case I found it there: [Virtualbox_forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=46523) and there: [python_doc](https://pythonhosted.org/pyglet/api/pyglet.window.key-module.html)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Win XP host, Win XP guest.  What I found is that it's not enough to enter your new key combo and select OK.

You have to enter your new key combo in the text box, then click in another box as if you're going to edit something else.  Then the changes will stick.

File -> Preferences -> Input -> Virtual Machine

Comment: Awesome tip! Never thought such a weird behavior could even exist!! Tks.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that appeared in VirtualBox 4.3.8 (maybe earlier?). [It got fixed](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12828) in [VirtualBox 4.3.14](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.14/).